# Favourite places in vim

Tags: vim, bookmarks, vim-plugin

Is there a command in `vim` that can bookmark a place (path to the file, line number in that file), so that I can go to that place easily later?

It would be similar as `NERDTree` `:Bookmark` command. You can open your file with `NERDTreeFromBookmark`. I'm looking for the same functionality with the difference that bookmark is not only a file but file + line number.

Thank you

Comment: Tags are the closest I can think of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `viminfo` setting can contain the option `!`, which makes it store any global variables with uppercase letters in the viminfo file. Using this, you can define a variable called `g:BOOKMARKS` and store your bookmarks in there.

Here's some vimscript you could use to do that:

```
set viminfo+=!

if !exists('g:BOOKMARKS')
  let g:BOOKMARKS = {}
endif

" Add the current [filename, cursor position] in g:BOOKMARKS under the given
" name
command! -nargs=1 Bookmark call s:Bookmark(<f-args>)
function! s:Bookmark(name)
  let file   = expand('%:p')
  let cursor = getpos('.')

  if file != ''
    let g:BOOKMARKS[a:name] = [file, cursor]
  else
    echom "No file"
  endif

  wviminfo
endfunction

" Delete the user-chosen bookmark
command! -nargs=1 -complete=custom,s:BookmarkNames DelBookmark call s:DelBookmark(<f-args>)
function! s:DelBookmark(name)
  if !has_key(g:BOOKMARKS, a:name)
    return
  endif

  call remove(g:BOOKMARKS, a:name)
  wviminfo
endfunction

" Go to the user-chosen bookmark
command! -nargs=1 -complete=custom,s:BookmarkNames GotoBookmark call s:GotoBookmark(<f-args>)
function! s:GotoBookmark(name)
  if !has_key(g:BOOKMARKS, a:name)
    return
  endif

  let [filename, cursor] = g:BOOKMARKS[a:name]

  exe 'edit '.filename
  call setpos('.', cursor)
endfunction

" Completion function for choosing bookmarks
function! s:BookmarkNames(A, L, P)
  return join(sort(keys(g:BOOKMARKS)), "\n")
endfunction
```

I'm not sure how readable the code is, but basically, the `Bookmark` command accepts a single parameter to use as a name. It will store the current filename and cursor position to the `g:BOOKMARKS` dictionary. You can use the `GotoBookmark` command with a mark name to go to it. `DelBookmark` works in the same way, but deletes the given mark. Both functions are tab-completed.

Another way to jump through them is by using this command:

```
" Open all bookmarks in the quickfix window
command! CopenBookmarks call s:CopenBookmarks()
function! s:CopenBookmarks()
  let choices = []

  for [name, place] in items(g:BOOKMARKS)
    let [filename, cursor] = place

    call add(choices, {
          \ 'text':     name,
          \ 'filename': filename,
          \ 'lnum':     cursor[1],
          \ 'col':      cursor[2]
          \ })
  endfor

  call setqflist(choices)
  copen
endfunction
```

`CopenBookmarks` will load the bookmarks in the quickfix window, which seems like a nice interface to me.

This solution is similar to Eric's -- it uses the `.viminfo` file, so if something goes wrong with it, you'll probably lose your marks. And if you save your marks in one vim instance, they won't be immediately available in another.

I don't know how comfortable your are with vimscript, so just in case -- to use this, you can put the code in a file under your `plugin` vimfiles directory, for example `plugin/bookmarks.vim`. Should be completely enough. Here's the entire code in a gist as well: https://gist.github.com/1371174

**EDIT**: Changed the interface for the solution a bit. Original version can be found in the gist history.

Comment: Your solution looks best so far, but it has one drawback yet. In NERDTree the :Bookmark command has one argument (the name of the bookmark) and when you open the bookmark with :NERDTreeFromBookmark you can type only a few characters and then cycle with TAB and choose one of the bookmarks. Would it be hard to add this functionality?

Comment: That does sound like a better interface. I haven't really used NERDTree's bookmark capabilities, so I went with something I came up with myself. Anyway, I updated my response. By the way, if you get a "type mismatch" error, try executing an `unlet g:BOOKMARKS`. The variable is a hash now, instead of an array, and since it's persisted, you might bump into that.

Comment: This works very good. I can't see a bug so far and behaves exactly as I wished. Thanks a lot for applying your scripting knowledge.

Comment: That's only strange that the bookmarks disappeared after restarting computer.

Comment: That's odd. I don't seem to lose the bookmarks after restarts. What kind of OS are you using? Is there any possibility that your `.viminfo` file is placed in some temporary directory or something (pretty unlikely, though)?

Comment: I used Xubuntu 10.04. Now I'm on Lubuntu 11.10 and it works after restart. But I will rather backup, because I don't know how this `.viminfo` works and if I can trust it. (btw. I asked a question on how to modify your script to save bookmarks to ordinary file)

Comment: Yesterday I made a few bookmarks, but today they aren't in `.viminfo` in structure under `# global variables:` comment, they just disappeared.

Comment: It seems `.viminfo` is not very stable after all. I'll see what I can do about persisting them to their own file.

Comment: If you would know, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211526/vimscript-using-another-file-instead-of-viminfo) is my question about it.

Answer (score 20):

Yes you can do so with the 'mark' command.  There are two types of bookmarks you can create, local and global.  You are referring to a global bookmark.

You can type 'mP' to create a bookmark called P.  Notice the case, uppercase indicates it is a global bookmark.  To go to that bookmark, type `P.

Hope this helps

[Source](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/02/how-to-add-bookmarks-inside-vi-and-vim-editor/)

Comment: And I had no idea they're persistent :)

Comment: @Eric LaForce I have to reopen the question because in this solution there are drawbacks in opposite to NERDTree. The bookmarks can be only one letter long, so I have to remember these letters. When I go to bookmark in NERDTree it behaves more elegant. I type `NERDTreeFromBookmark` and then I can cycle with <kbd>tab</kbd> through my string bookmarks beginning e.g. on `prj_`. Other drawback of marks is limited number of bookmarks I can create.

Comment: I would go ahead and edit your question as well to include this additional information.  I assume since you are comparing vim to NERDTree, you do not want any plugins, i.e. you are looking for a native vim solution?

Comment: NERDTree bookmarks work effectively than mark. I will start a bounty and if there isn't better solution I will accept this.

Comment: @xralf You can see list of marks in vim by entering `:marks` (so you don't have to remember them). But unfortunately global mark names should be from `{A-Z0-9}`, so you're right, they're limited to only 36 fixed choices (no custom naming).

Comment: @saeedn I think similar functionality as NERDTree could be possible with vimscript (we need only to remember line number + path). I'm just beginning with scripts, so I'm rather asking.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker, I'm not sure they're always persistent. If I create a mark like `mM`, but then close the buffer with `:bw` before closing vim, the mark is removed.

Comment: @BradyTrainor, now, 3 years later I have to admit I haven't made any use of the things I've learned here, so I haven't got to check it. And from the stuff above it's not clear to me why I mention persistence… Maybe I've read up on it back then. There could also be exceptions. Anyway, I don't remember a thing now, I use vim daily, but I hardly ever use bookmarks…

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker, I was wrong, they are persistent, if you use `:bd[elete]` instead. The documentation `:h bwipeout` says  as much.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [this script (number marks)](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2194). There might be better ones though. Wait for other answers!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't solve your problem as stated, but you may find it helps.

[MRU.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=521) - Most Recently Used files plugin

Type `:MRU` and you get a nice searchable list of your most recently used files. Pressing enter on one brings you to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
" When editing a file, always jump to the last known cursor position.
" And open enough folds to make the cursor is not folded
" Don't do it when the position is invalid or when inside an event handler
" (happens when dropping a file on gvim).
autocmd BufWinEnter *
            \ if line("'\"") <= line("$") |
            \   exe "normal! g`\"" | exe "normal! zv" |
            \ endif
```