# vimscript using another file instead of .viminfo

Tags: vim

I installed a vimscript written by expert in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063848/favourite-places-in-vim/8157924#8157924) question.

But there is one problem in the script. When I restart the computer, the bookmarks saved by the script will disappear.

Is it possible to store the bookmarks to **another file** (e.g. **mybookmarks.txt**) instead of `.viminfo` file? Bookmarks stored in `.viminfo` disappear unpredictably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems like a good tool in general, I extracted it to a plugin: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3826. This would store bookmarks only, regardless of viminfo settings, in `~/.vim_bookmarks`. The filename is configurable by changing `g:simple_bookmarks_filename`.

Since it's a full blown plugin now, you can send bug reports on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/simple_bookmarks.vim/issues), so if it's not working quite right, let me know.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad to see how to realize things and how vimscripting is useful too.

Comment: I have a little idea for future features. The command `:CopenBookmarks` has nicer interface that `TagBar` or `TagList` plugins. If this could cooperate with `ctags` there could be commands similar to `:CopenBookmarks` e.g. `:CopenFunctions` or `:CopenVariables` and we could browse through existing functions or variables present in current buffer.

Comment: I'm glad I'm getting you excited about vim scripting :). I can see how these could be useful, although they don't really have too much to do with bookmarks :). The interface is actually pretty standard for Vim, it's called the [quickfix window](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#quickfix). There's a ton of stuff you can do with it. I have a [blog post](http://andrewradev.com/2011/10/15/vim-and-ctags-finding-tag-definitions/) that touches on the subject, though it might not be very readable for a beginner.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Use the [`'viminfo n'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27viminfo%27) option.

From `:he 'viminfo'`:

> Name of the viminfo file.  The name must immediately follow
>           the 'n'.  Must be the last one!  If the "-i" argument was
>           given when starting Vim, that file name overrides the one
>           given here with 'viminfo'.  Environment variables are expanded
>           when opening the file, not when setting the option.

Comment: Could you show that in the vimscript from the question? I'd like to do it without `viminfo`, not renaming `.viminfo` but save it to ordinary file.